# exclude index php of wordpress from being wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I want to use wordpress to manage my content but I want to build my own homepage `(index.php)` with custom html. How do I do rewrite rule in .htaccess so that when I go to mysite.com it render it own content instead of calling the wordpress's stuff?

Comment: Try `DirectoryIndex first.php second.php third.php index.php`, where first.php is your first option, second.php your second option and so on.

Comment: @agustin can I create a folder and put first.php in?

Comment: files don't need to be relative to the directory. So you can use `DirectoryIndex /first/index.php /second/index.php /third/index.php index.php`

Comment: I would recommend to make a [static front page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_a_Static_Front_Page). You then use a custom [Page Template](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/) to add your HTML stuff in it.